# What date do you want to book this FOR?

Tags: grammar

Let's say there is a traveler who wanted to book a bus trip to go a tourist spot.

> Customer: Hello, I want to book a trip to go to XYZ tourist spot.
>
> Agent: Sure, what date do you want to book this **for**?

My question is, why do you have to include the preposition "for" at the end when it is relatively ok to not include that?

Comment: I think you mean *What reason **might** you have (for including the preposition)?*, given that you know it's "relatively ok" ***not*** to.

Answer (score 3):

It aligns with the idea that the booking is "for" a particularly date, i.e. the booking belongs to, or is intended to belong to, that date. (It is similar to buying a gift "for" its recipient.)

If we removed "for":

> Sure, what date do you want to book this?

This would actually refer to the date on which the booking was made, i.e. the current date in your example, as opposed to the date the booking was actually for.

Comment: +1 Yeah. Without the *for* you could reply *I'd like to book [it] today please!* or *I'll phone back tomorrow to make the booking!*

Comment: (1) *"**When** do you want to book this?"* (2) *"**On** what date do you want to book this?"* Both of those sound more natural than either presented version.